# Could not find module ‘Test.QuickCheck’ on Windows

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

My ghci version is 8.4.3

I tried

```
stack install QuickCheck
```

Something was installed. But when I input `import Test.QuickCheck`, it tells `Could not find module ‘Test.QuickCheck’` again. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Firstly, [`stack install` is not recommended](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2018/02/10/an-opinionated-guide-to-haskell-in-2018/#understanding-stacks-model-and-avoiding-its-biggest-gotcha) for installing executables or libraries. Instead, there's a couple of things you can do to use the `QuickCheck` library:

- If you want to use `QuickCheck` in a command such as `stack ghci` or `stack ghc`, you can add it as a `--package` option e.g. to run a REPL to play around with `QuickCheck` you can use `stack ghci --package QuickCheck` and then write `import Test.QuickCheck`.
- If you want to write a small one-file program using `QuickCheck`, then you can run `stack ghc --package QuickCheck -- MyProgram.hs` (using the `--package` option from the last bullet point). Alternately, you can use `stack`'s [scripting functionality](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#script-interpreter) and include a line such as this at the top of your program:

  `-- stack --resolver lts-12.18 script --package QuickCheck`
- If you want to use `QuickCheck` in a large project, then add it as a dependency in your `my-program.cabal` or `project.yaml` file.

The same guidance applies to any package you may want to use.

Answer (score 4):

```
myos>cabal update
myos>cabal install --lib QuickCheck
myos>ghci
gchi> import Test.QuickCheck
```